# Python: CSV Traceback Error

Tags: python, csv

I'm using python to create a program that involves me creating a CSV file and storing details in this file. I also need the program to read from the file and print the specified details. The following code shows how I have implemented the CSV file and how I make the program read from it.

```
with open("SpeedTracker.csv", "a", newline="") as csvfile:
  writeToFile=csv.writer(csvfile)
  writeToFile.writerow([("Reg: ",RegistrationPlate),('First Camera Time:',FirstCameraTime),("Second Camera Time:",SecondCameraTime),("Average Speed:",AverageSpeed2,"MPH"),])

with open('SpeedTracker.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
  SpeedDetails = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
  for Reg, Average in SpeedDetails:
    print(Reg, Average)
```

However, when ever I run the code and follow the instructions as a user, I get an error that I can't understand. The error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 24, in <module>
    for Reg, Average in SpeedDetails:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
exited with non-zero status
```

I don't know what I'm supposed to do to correct this. Can someone please show me where I'm going wrong and teach me the right method so that I know what to do in the future?

Thanks a lot for the help,
Mohammed.

Comment: Average speed has three elements.

Comment: You're writing four elements to each line,  but trying to read back only two. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I only read two elements because that's all I need. The other two aren't really needed for the next bit. Should I read all four or is there another way for me to write four but only read two??

Comment: @StephenRauch I don't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: @MohammedAwais you have to unpack all 4 elements but just print the 2 of interest.

Comment: @Gabriel Thank a lot. That works now. But whenever the program prints the details that are requested, it prints them twice. Why is that??

Comment: @Gabriel or just use a slice like `SpeedDetails[:2]` or possibly just unpack directly those required and the remaining to a list, eg: `for reg, avg, *rest in SpeedDetails`...

Comment: @JonClements It works now, but when I ask the program to print the details from the CSV file, it prints everything that's in the file. I only need the details that the user has just entered, how do I achieve this??

Comment: @MohammedAwais that's a completely different question and there's not enough information to answer it - how do you know what details the user has just entered - how do they enter them etc...?

Comment: @JonClements is there a way to private message you?? it will be easier to explain. If not I'll just show you here.

Comment: Nope - there isn't private messaging. Try and put together a complete stand-alone example (see how to create a [mcve]) including inputs/outputs, how you get the user input, the code that does the printing etc and describing what you're getting, what you want to get etc... and then you should be in a position to pose it as a question that anyone can help you with.

Comment: @JonClements Basically this program asks the user to input the following details:
1: Registration of a vehicle
2: Distance between both speed cameras
3: Time the vehicle passed both cameras

these details are then used to determine the validity of the vehicle details and the average speed of the vehicle to ultimately decide whether the vehicle is using real/fake plates and if the vehicle is speeding or not.
these inputs are stored in the CSV file, but I need the program to read and print the most recent inputs from the user, not all of them that are stored in the file. How do I do this?

Comment: Read what I said above about formulating a [mcve] and a proper question - put your effort into that will help you get answer rather than pinging me in comments (which won't). Thanks.

Comment: Gives you a good amount of time to write the best question ever that's going to get you upvotes and trusted by the system so you're not quite so limited then  - doesn't it :) (and failing that - plenty of time to play with ideas and possibly even solve it yourself)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('SpeedTracker.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    rows = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in rows:
        for SpeedDetails in row:
            reg = row[0]
            firstCam = row[1]
            secondCam = row[2]
            AvgSpeed = row[3]

            print(reg)
            print(firstCam)
            print(secondCam)
            print(AvgSpeed)
```

There are two problems the code you gave. 1) You need to loop over each row before you start trying to retrieve the data in the columns. 2) There are four items in each row, but you are trying to stick these four items into two variables (`reg`, and `Average`)

But a more ideal way of doing this would be to write out the csv headers, and create a more normal looking CSV file. Like so.

```
import csv
import os

RegistrationPlate = FirstCameraTime = SecondCameraTime = AverageSpeed2 = 2

with open("SpeedTracker.csv", "a", newline="") as csvfile:
    writeToFile=csv.writer(csvfile)

    #if the csv headers have not been written yet, write them
    if os.path.getsize("SpeedTracker.csv") == 0:
        writeToFile.writerow(["Reg", "First Camera Time", "Second Camera Time", "Average Speed"])

    writeToFile.writerow([RegistrationPlate,FirstCameraTime,SecondCameraTime,AverageSpeed2])

with open('SpeedTracker.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    rows = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(rows) #skip headers

    for row in rows:
        reg = row[0]
        firstCam = row[1]
        secondCam = row[2]
        AvgSpeed = row[3]

        print(reg)
        print(firstCam)
        print(secondCam)
        print(AvgSpeed)
```

Comment: After the help Gabriel gave, it seems to work now. Thank for the help though.